# How to target elements under clicked with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide everything under (but leave the ones above) the element that was clicked by the user. Check out this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dS2vA/

So if you click on the 2nd `<li>` the three `<li>`s under it should be hidden. If you click the 4th `<li>`, only the 5th element should be hidden.

I tried doing it with `:not('clicked')` but that targets the elements above the clicked element, as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Side note, you could also just do `$('ul li').removeClass();` inside of your click event instead of that `each` loop.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS The OP wants to remove classes on every click ;)

Comment: @VisioN editied & changed, whoops!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the following:

```
$(this).nextAll().hide();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/dS2vA/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('ul li').click(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function() {
        $(this).removeClass();
    })
    $(this).nextAll("li").slice(0,3).addClass('clicked');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to **VisioN**'s answer, to be more specific you can add a selector filter ("li") to `nextAll()` like this:

```
$(this).nextAll("li").hide();
```

Comment: No need, since in valid markup all siblings of `<li>` element should also be `<li>` elements.

Comment: yup in this example it's not required but it would be helpful in cases where you have other types of child elements.